# Need to rename multiple files via VBScript in a particular folder

Tags: vbscript, filenames, file-rename

I need to rename multiple files via VBScript in a particular folder

Example:

Change name to specific name with number convention such as Change Part1.csv to 31-AUG-20-1.csv  and Part2.csv to 31-Aug-29-2.csv

Here 31-Aug-20 will remain same but with a incremental number. Therefore in below code i don't want to give new name i.e. 31-Aug-20-1.csv against each file rather it should change to 31-Aug-20(incremental numbering)

```
 Dim fso, folder, file, folderName, dict
    
    'Path
    folderName = "C:\User\desktop\ATL\"
    
    'Future FileName
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "Part1.csv", "ATL-31-Aug-20-1.csv"
    dict.Add "Part2.csv", "ATL-31-Aug-20-2.csv"
    dict.Add "Part3.csv", "ATL-31-Aug-20-3.csv"
    dict.Add "Part4.csv", "ATL-31-Aug-20-4.csv"
    dict.Add "Part5.csv", "ATL-31-Aug-20-5.csv"
    dict.Add "Part6.csv", "ATL-31-Aug-20-6.csv"
    
    ' Create filesystem object and the folder object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  
    
    ' Loop over all files in the folder until the searchFileName is found
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If dict.Exists(file.Name) Then file.Name = dict(file.Name)
    Next
```

Comment: Should the increment number match the part number or should the increment just keep increasing with every new file?

Comment: Yes - the increment number needs to be in line with Part number. for e.g.

I have only 7 files on weekly basis srating from Part1.csv till Part7.csv and i need to rename them with specific name i.e. ATL-01-SEP-20-1.csv till ATL-01-SEP-20-7.csv

Comment: @aDDy So what is the problem, did you get an error if so what was it? The question doesn't explain what the problem is, so how do you expect us to provide a solution? That code looks fine to me although I've not tested it.

Comment: I tested the code. It renames the files correctly ie Part1.csv -> ATL-31-Aug-20-1.csv. Or do you want a dynamic rename  ie  Part#.csv -> ATL-31-Aug-20-#.csv ?

Comment: @Mike67 exactly my point, the MCVE works so doesn’t really help in understanding what the OPs requirement is and what they’ve tried to achieve it.

Comment: No i want to type change Part1, Part2 Part3 to ATL-31-Aug-20 but with incremental number.. I don't want to define ATL-31-Aug-20-1, ATL-31-Aug-20-2 against each Part file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will rename the files with incremental numbering:

```
Dim iCounter
Dim folderName
Dim fso, folder, file

' Path
folderName = "C:\User\desktop\ATL\"

' Create filesystem object and the folder object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  

iCounter = 1
For Each file In folder.Files
    file.Name = "ATL-32-Aug-20-" & iCounter & ".csv"
    iCounter = iCounter + 1
Next
```

If you want to keep the number from the original file name (Part#.csv), you can add the following logic:

```
Const vbTextCompare = 1
Dim folderName
Dim fso, folder, file
Dim sNumber
Dim sPrefix

' Path and prefix
folderName = "C:\User\desktop\ATL\"
sPrefix = "ATL-32-Aug-20-"

' Create filesystem object and the folder object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  

For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Check for "Part" and ".csv" in file name
    If StrComp(Left(file.Name, 4), "Part", vbTextCompare) = 0 And StrComp(Right(file.Name, 4), ".csv", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ' Extract number
        sNumber = Mid(file.Name, 5, Len(file.Name) - 8)
        ' Rename file
        file.Name = sPrefix & sNumber & ".csv"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Etienne but the above code is giving error - Line 3 Char 1 and Error: Object Required: 'folder'.  Furthermore, how to define folder path in above code?

Comment: This is code to integrate with your existing code where the `folder` variable is defined.